# Mysql show count on join even if count is 0

Tags: mysql, join

Sorry if my title isn't clear. I’m trying to make a lobby system for my card game. When a user presses join game I want the server to check how much space is available in the game they’ve selected then add them to the team with the least players (currently always 1 player on each team but I’d like to expand it to 2 players per team at some point and possibly more than 2 teams).

The tables I have are:

**game_teams**

```
game_id, team_id, score
```

**game_players**

```
user_id, game_id, team_id
```

With game_teams team_id isn't unique or auto-incremented because it seemed like more overhead to have a unique value for every team in every game when they're mostly just there for player placement. So all games have teams 1-2 or 1-3 depending on team count if that makes sense.

The output I’m hoping for is something like:

```
game_id | team_id | team_size

   8 |     1 |      1

   8 |     2 |      0
```

Currently the queries I have are as below but they don’t do what I’m expecting.

This returns all players in team 1 and all players in team 2 ignoring the game id

```
SELECT games.game_id, COUNT(game_players.user_id) AS team_size, game_teams2.team_id 
FROM games 
JOIN game_teams2 ON games.game_id=game_teams2.game_id 
JOIN game_players ON game_players.team_id=game_teams2.team_id
WHERE games.game_id=1 GROUP BY game_teams2.team_id
```

This seems to be nearly right but it only returns teams that already have at least 1 player in them where I really need 0 to be returned if the team has no players associated with it.

```
SELECT game_players.game_id, 
COUNT(game_players.user_id) AS team_size, game_players.team_id 
FROM game_players WHERE game_players.game_id=8 GROUP BY game_players.team_id
```

I'm not quite sure what else to try to get the desired output.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need a left join and count is null, remember join means inner join I. E. There needs to be a match on keys in both tables for rows to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create the distinct set of `game_id` and `team_id` from `game_teams` and then left join it with `game_players`.

Something like

```
SELECT x.game_id,
       x.team_id,
       count(gp.user_id) AS team_size
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT game_id,
                   team_id
   FROM game_teams
   WHERE game_id = 8) x
LEFT JOIN game_players gp ON x.game_id = gp.game_id
AND x.team_id = gp.team_id
```

You need to take care of nulls for the `gp.user_id`. I have not tested this, this is just an idea.